# How to generate Angular page using Ionic without automatically adding new route

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Currently, I am using `ionic g page myPageName` to generate new Angular 10 pages using the Ionic CLI. However, every page generated automatically adds a new route to my `app-routing.module.ts` file. In it, I have a `let routes: Routes = [...];` that comes with Ionic's generated starter template which is what gets added to.

I have tried looking into available CLI options using `npx ng g page --help` and have tried setting some of the available options in my `angular.json` config file, such as `"route-path": ""`, but they did not achieve what I wanted. Config options such as `"spec": false` did work successfully however, so it is not an issue with the configuration file itself.